# Error-Null pointer Exception

Tags: java, jdbc

here in this i want fetch some data in combo box by clicking on a button from db that already contain some name at 101 id....

```
try {
    con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:odbc:nit");
    pst = con.prepareStatement("select name from [Sheet1$] where id = ?");
    pst.setString(1, "101");
    try {
        while (rs.next()) {
            ComboBox1.addItem(rs.getString("name"));
        }
        pst.close();
        con.close();
    } catch (NullPointerException e2) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "ER:-" + e2);

    }
} catch (Exception e) {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error" + e);
}
```

Comment: Which line is being flagged for throwing the NullPointerException? One of the variables on that line is not instantiated. Instantiate it, problem solved.

Comment: I assume that your problem might be with `rs`

Comment: something else i declare my rs variable ResultSet rs but stil it  is not working this coding at a burrons click

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't declare and initialize variable `rs` type of `ResultSet`. You need to execute the `PreparedStament` and assign the return to `rs`